# Grails - How to use named queries inside Criteria

Tags: grails

I have a case where, i need to use a named query inside a Criteria. But it doesnt work!

Is it possible to use named Query inside criteria? If yes how?

Comment: Can you post *how* it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Was my answer useful in achieving what you wanted from `namedQuery`? If yes, then accept the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

But you can use a `namedQuery` from one class in `namedQuery` of another class. Refer [this JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9327). (mainly Jeff's comment)

Comment: Link in broken 404

Comment: Yes this was 3 years ago, grails issues moved from JIRA to github. I am having trouble finding it now.